# Why is the apostrophe sign a valid path separator in Perl

Tags: perl, syntax

In Perl, you call modules using `::` as path separator. So, if you have a module on `site/lib/GD/Image.pm`, you call `use GD::Image`.

However, long time ago I found out that you can also call `use GD'Image` and things like `my $img = new GD'Image;`, and there are also modules on CPAN using that syntax on ther names/documentation.

What is the purpose or logic behind that? Is it maybe, as many things in Perl, just a feature intended to *humanize* sentences and allow you to create and use modules like [Acme::Don't](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Acme-Don-t-1.00/t.pm)?

Does it have any other intention different to `::`?

Comment: Otherwise how would we [program in Klingon](https://metacpan.org/module/Lingua::tlhInganHol::yIghun#SYNOPSIS)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [perlmod](http://p3rl.org/perlmod) for explanation:

> The old package delimiter was a single quote, but double colon is now the preferred delimiter

So, the reason is history.

Answer (score 6):

The single quote is an old ADA separator. However, it didn't play well with Emacs, so the double colon became used.

Good God! ADA? Emacs? I am old.